# Button click does not show title in an alert when tooltip is active using jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, css, tooltip, buttonclick

I am trying to show an alert with jQuery for a button click that displays the value of the title attribute in an alert. I am unable to show it, the alert message displays an empty string. [Here is my trails](http://jsfiddle.net/jkLzuh0o/4/)

Clicking on `#btn1` shows empty title. Why is the title attribute cleared on click?

Is `$(document).tooltip` impacting some how? I removed `$(document).tooltip` function and it's working. I am trying to make it work with jQuery UI tooltip.

```
<p>Your age:
    <input type=text title="We ask for your age only for statistical purposes.">
</p>
<p>
    <input type="button" id="btn1" title="This a test enabled button." value="hover me please">
</p>
<p>
    <input type="button" disabled="disabled" id="btn2" title="This a test disabled button." value="hover me please">
</p>

$(function () {
    $(document).on("click","#btn1", function () {
        alert($(this).attr("title"));
    });

    $(document).on("click","#btn2", function () {
        alert($(this).attr("title"));
    });

 $(document).tooltip({
        position: {
            my: "center bottom-20",
            at: "center top",
            using: function (position, feedback) {
                $(this).css(position);
                $("<div>")
                    .addClass("arrow")
                    .addClass(feedback.vertical)
                    .addClass(feedback.horizontal)
                    .appendTo(this);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I believe the `$.tooltip` function removes the title attribute, adding it to the DIV it creates, which is why your button doesn't display the title. I can't find any note of it in the documentation, but in your fiddle, commenting out the tooltip call and clicking the button showed the title.

Comment: @Jhecht, I confirmed that when the tool tip is active the issue is reproducible, but at no other time. Please see my answer and 2 possible workarounds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On line 16182 of [jQuery UI](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js) (ctrl-F for "`target.removeAttr( "title" );`") you can see the `title` attribute is removed. The comments above this line explain exactly why this is done.

The following are the comments from the jQuery UI file explaining why the value of the title attribute is removed.

```
// if we have a title, clear it to prevent the native tooltip  
// we have to check first to avoid defining a title if none exists  
// (we don't want to cause an element to start matching [title])  
//  
// We use removeAttr only for key events, to allow IE to export the correct  
// accessible attributes. For mouse events, set to empty string to avoid  
// native tooltip showing up (happens only when removing inside mouseover).
```

[**Here is a work around**](http://jsfiddle.net/jkLzuh0o/16/)

```
var btn1_title_at_load = $("#btn1").attr("title");
$(document).on("click","#btn1", function () {
    alert(btn1_title_at_load);
});
```

[**Here is an alternitive work around**](http://jsfiddle.net/jkLzuh0o/7/).

```
<input type="button" id="btn1" title="This a test enabled button." 
       value="hover me please" 
       data-title="This a test enabled button." />

$(document).on("click","#btn1", function () {
    var t = $(this).data("title");
    window.alert(t);
});
```

Supporting evidence.

[**Programmatically click the button on page load**](http://jsfiddle.net/jkLzuh0o/17/) *note that the hover event is not active on page load.*

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<p>Your age:
    <input type=text title="We ask for your age only for statistical purposes.">
</p>
<p>
    <input type="button" id="btn1" title="This a test enabled button." value="hover me please">
</p>
<p>
    <input type="button" disabled="disabled" id="btn2" title="This a test disabled button." value="hover me please">
</p>

$(function () {
    $("#btn1").click(function () {
        alert($(this).attr("title"));
    });

    $("#btn2").click(function () {
        alert($(this).attr("title"));
    });

 $(document).tooltip({
        position: {
            my: "center bottom-20",
            at: "center top",
            using: function (position, feedback) {
                $(this).css(position);
                $("<div>")
                    .addClass("arrow")
                    .addClass(feedback.vertical)
                    .addClass(feedback.horizontal)
                    .appendTo(this);
            }
        }
    });

    });
```

The JQuery command is .click() on your button element. This can work.

**EDIT**

I just checked on my local machine, there is nothing wrong with your code, try including the jquery script as follows:

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

It might work after it.

Comment: Sorry Prasad. I have to use Jquery 2+ edge version in my project so unable to use 1.91. version. It is not working with 2.1.

Comment: tried with jquery 1.9 version and it did not work. here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jkLzuh0o/6/

Comment: Actually, if you remove, jquery-ui.js from your external resources, your code will work.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this if you like.

```
$(function () {
     $(document).on("click","#btn1", function () {
        alert($(this).attr("title2"));
    });   
    $(document).on("click","#btn2", function () {
        alert($(this).attr("title"));
    });


    $(document).tooltip({
        position: {
            my: "center bottom-20",
            at: "center top",
            using: function (position, feedback) {
                $(this).css(position);
                $("<div>")
                    .addClass("arrow")
                    .addClass(feedback.vertical)
                    .addClass(feedback.horizontal)
                    .appendTo(this);
            }
        }
    });
    });
```

and your inputwill be like this

```
  <input type="button" id="btn1" title="This a test enabled button." title2="This a test enabled button." value="hover me please">
```

Answer (score 1):

Using another attribute can solve your problem.

`data-alert`

Check the code below:

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on("click", "#btn1", function() {
    alert($(this).attr("data-alert"));
  });

  $(document).on("click", "#btn2", function() {
    alert($(this).attr("data-alert"));
  });


  $(document).tooltip({
    position: {
      my: "center bottom-20",
      at: "center top",
      using: function(position, feedback) {
        $(this).css(position);
        $("<div>")
          .addClass("arrow")
          .addClass(feedback.vertical)
          .addClass(feedback.horizontal)
          .appendTo(this);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-tooltip,
.arrow:after {
  background: black;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
.ui-tooltip {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font: bold 14px"Helvetica Neue", Sans-Serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px black;
}
.arrow {
  width: 70px;
  height: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -35px;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.arrow.top {
  top: -16px;
  bottom: auto;
}
.arrow.left {
  left: 20%;
}
.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: -20px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  box-shadow: 6px 5px 9px -9px black;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.arrow.top:after {
  bottom: -20px;
  top: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p>Your age:
  <input type=text title="We ask for your age only for statistical purposes.">
</p>
<p>
  <input type="button" id="btn1" title="This a test enabled button." data-alert="This a test enabled button." value="hover me please">
</p>
<p>
  <input type="button" disabled="disabled" id="btn2" title="This a test disabled button." value="hover me please">
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the above answers are correct. Here I showed another alternative way may this way is bit long.

```js
$(document).on("click","#btn1", function () {
        var title_ref = $(this).attr("aria-describedby");
        var title = $("#"+title_ref+" .ui-tooltip-content").text()
        alert(title);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You can not use title attribute in input as [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) link says, it is not as per standards, I added your title's text to name field and in alert it is showing the text [update fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/techprasad/jkLzuh0o/18/)

if it is the answer then accept this answer.

```
 alert($(this).attr("name"));
```